# Accessing JSON constant in date prototype

Tags: javascript, json, date, prototype

I have some JSON data setup in a structure similar to the one below in **Data.prototype.DAYSASTEXT**

I want to access this from inside a function I am using to extend the `Date()` method.

Here's the code: -

```
Date.prototype.DAYSSASTEXT = { "hours": [
  { "0": "Sunday" },
  { "3": "Wednesday" }
  ]
};

Date.prototype.getHourName = function() {
  // Edited
  return this.DAYSSASTEXT.hours[0][this.getDay()];
};


var example_date = new Date(2008, 1, 20);

document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = example_date.getHourName();
```

Where am I going wrong? the date set in example_date should return 3 for Wednesday.

**Edit:** If I change the day to a date that is a Sunday it returns the correct value but for Wednesday (day 3 when starting at 0) it returns undefined

Comment: There's no JSON data in the code shown. Object and array literals are not JSON.

Comment: The structure is valid JSON, I haven't included the data file because its too long.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the structure shown isn't JSON at all. JSON is a _string_ representation (where the content of the string has roughly the same format as a JS object literal or array literal) and has to be parsed for use as an object the way your `getHoursName()` function uses it. (I'm just objecting to the terminology as applied to the code shown.)

Comment: Fair enough, I welcome being corrected on my terminology I know it's not one of my stronger points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `'Expected an identifier and instead saw "["`

You have to use either [dot or bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) for member acccess, not both:

```
this.DAYSSASTEXT.hours[0][this.getDay()];
//                       ^ no dot!
```

Apart from that, your structure seems wrong. Not only that you have weekday names in an `hours` property, but you also have one-property objects in an array. I'd suggest to use either one big object, or even make that object an array:

```
Date.prototype.DAYSSASTEXT = {
    "hours": {
        "0": "Sunday",
        "3": "Wednesday"
    }
};
// or
Date.prototype.DAYSSASTEXT = {
   "hours": ["Sunday", , , "Wednesday"]
};
```

then access it without the array index `0`:

```
this.DAYSSASTEXT.hours[this.getDay()];
```

If you really needed that wrapping array for some reason, you at least have to put `Sunday` and `Wednesday` on the same object.

Comment: If I cannot change the structure of the JSON file what do you suggest? ignore the hours prop as I've added that to make the structure the same.

Comment: Why can't you change it? It's unusable currently. If you cannot change the code literal, you at least will have to add code that transforms it into above format.

Comment: I can change the structure of the JSON file but am not sure how to progress this is my second day with JSON, All the configs are required in one file, so for example all the days of the week, hours as text etc in one structured file that I can load and set as constants for the Date method to use when needed. I had them as separate objects because I thought I could match 0 and return Sunday that way.

Comment: Yeah, but you had to loop over the structure to "*match 0*". Build it so that you can directly access it "by 0"

Comment: Think I've cracked it. Thanks man, really appreciate the advice and pointing in the right direction!